# How to get apt-get to call apt-fast?

Tags: apt

Have been using `apt-fast` for a while now and really liking it. In case you don't know it is useful to speed up apt-get. However, I have a few questions regarding `apt-fast`:

1. I would like to make any call to `apt-get` run `apt-fast`. I'm assuming I can put a script called "`apt-get`" in my `~/bin` folder that executes `apt-fast`... so maybe I'm answering my own question on this first one.

   Would a script like this work?

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   exec apt-fast $@
   exit 0
   ```
2. `apt-fast` does not seem to speed up the very thing I wish it sped up most - `apt-get update`

   I would like `apt-fast` to make `apt-get update` run faster. Is this possible?

Comment: why you want to run `apt-get` instead of `apt-fast`, `apt-fast` has only 1 char more than `apt-get`

Comment: hmm. I'm hoping this question doesn't get off topic. But I will say that I prefer apt-fast because it is faster when downloading binaries. I'm concerned that it doesn't speed up the apt-cache apt-get update calls though.

Comment: My script I wrote above does seem to work without any trouble. Still want to know if apt-fast speeds up "apt-fast update" or if I can do anything to download the apt-get update information in threads

Comment: How did you conclude that `apt-fast` doesn't speed up the update and just speeds up getting binaries? (I use apt-fast as well.)

Comment: I'm concluding that for two reasons. 1) apt-get update and apt-fast update don't seem to be any different in speed at all from my overall feeling. and 2) the apt-fast install interface and apt-fast update interface are different. Apt-fast install actually gives me feedout of how things are being sped up ... it looks way different from apt-get install. but apt-fast update just gives me the same visually as apt-get update. Does anyone actually know that anything different is going on with updates?

Comment: You could consider asking [here](http://www.iloveubuntu.net/apt-fast-164-released-fixes-and-proper-configuration-dialog) or [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/~apt-fast).

Comment: As written in the iloveubuntu comment, I will look at it to also speedup update of package list.
apt-fast is a simple shellscript wrapper so tuning of apt-cache command would require some low level changes (directly in APT project). But that is not the design of apt-fast.

Comment: Hey @Lasall, thank you. Anyways. apt-fast was an awesome idea and it works really great for speeding up package downloads so I'm a very happy user. Much appreciation to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create an alias for `apt-get` in your home directory. To do so, follow these:

1. Open a terminal and do this command:

   ```
   touch ~/.bash_aliases; gedit ~/.bash_aliases
   ```
2. In the new opened file, type these and save and exit.

   ```
   alias apt-get='apt-fast'
   ```

Then, whenever you run `apt-get`, `apt-fast` will run instead

For more info, see this page

- http://modifyubuntu.com/#terminal

Answer (score 5):

**apt-fast** does not make 'apt-get update' faster. If you'll check the code, e.g.

```
vi /usr/bin/apt-fast
```

You'll find the line:

```
if echo "$@" | grep -q "upgrade\|install\|dist-upgrade"; then
...
else
apt-get "@"
```

Which means that `apt-fast` does nothing in all other commands except in upgrade, install, and dist-upgrade.

Comment: thank you. but very sad news. I really wish it would speed update up as well. I hate having to wait for all the PPA repos to download when doing apt-get update. it takes forever.