# Alias apt-get to apt-fast?

Tags: apt, alias, apt-fast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get apt-get to call apt-fast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168867/how-to-get-apt-get-to-call-apt-fast)

I use apt-fast, but often find myself copying commands from the internet, these all use apt-get.

I am wondering if it is possible (and what errors I might run into) to alias it so any apt-get commands actually run apt-fast.

The only issue I could see with this is if apt-fast uses apt-get internally anywhere?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't make an alias have the name of a command that already exist.

Comment: You can, it's just er... ill advised.

Comment: Isn't [apt-fast](https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast) similar to `sudo apt-get -o Acquire::Queue-Mode="access" update` ?

Comment: @Hailwood What's wrong with creating an alias that has the same name as an existing command? This is done all the time. For example, by default on Ubuntu, `grep` is an alias for `grep --color=auto`.